# Nodes with different energies in NS2

Tags: mobile, tcl

I am working on my project. It is about detection of selfish nodes depending on the energy of the node. Here I have 20 nodes of the same energy, then I added 5 more but with different energies. The program shows that there is an error (as listed at the end of the code).
My code

```
# Define options
set val(chan)           Channel/WirelessChannel    ;# channel type
set val(prop)           Propagation/TwoRayGround   ;# radio-propagation model
set val(netif)          Phy/WirelessPhy            ;# network interface type
set val(mac)            Mac/802_11                 ;# MAC type
set val(ifq)            Queue/DropTail             ;# interface queue type
set val(ll)             LL                         ;# link layer type
set val(ant)            Antenna/OmniAntenna        ;# antenna model
set val(ifqlen)         100000                         ;# max packet in ifq
set val(nn)             20                         ;# number of mobilenodes
set val(rp)             AODV                       ;# routing protocol
set val(x)              1000               ;# X dimension of topography
set val(y)              1000               ;# Y dimension of topography 
set val(seed)           0.0
set val(cp)             "cbr-20"
set val(sc)             "setdest-20"
set val(stop)       200.0              ;# time of simulation end
set ns_       [new Simulator]
set tracefile       [open aodvnode50.tr w]
#set windowVsTime2 [open win.tr w] 
$ns_ trace-all $tracefile
$ns_ use-newtrace 
#$ns_ namtrace-all-wireless $namtrace $val(x) $val(y)
# set up topography object
set topo       [new Topography]
$topo load_flatgrid $val(x) $val(y)
#Open the NAM trace file
set namfile [open manet.nam w]
$ns_ namtrace-all $namfile
$ns_ namtrace-all-wireless $namfile $val(x) $val(y)
set god_ [create-god $val(nn)]
set chan_1_ [new $val(chan)]
#
#  Create nn mobilenodes [$val(nn)] and attach them to the channel. 
#
# configure the nodes
        $ns_ node-config -adhocRouting $val(rp) \
             -llType $val(ll) \
             -macType $val(mac) \
             -ifqType $val(ifq) \
             -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \
             -antType $val(ant) \
             -propType $val(prop) \
             -phyType $val(netif) \
             -channel $chan_1_ \
             -topoInstance $topo \
             -agentTrace ON \
             -routerTrace ON \
             -macTrace ON \
-energyModel "EnergyModel" \
        -initialEnergy 100.0 \
        -txPower 2.0522 \
        -rxPower 0.0591 \
        -idlePower 0.00006 \
        -sleepPower 0.000003 \       
    for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn) } { incr i } {
        set node_($i) [$ns_ node]
                $node_($i) random-motion 0  ;# disable random motion
    }
$ns_ node-config -initialEnergy 500
set node_(20) [$ns_ node]
$ns_ node-config -initialEnergy 20
set node_(21) [$ns_ node]
$ns_ node-config -initialEnergy 30
set node_(22) [$ns_ node]
$ns_ node-config -initialEnergy 100
set node_(23) [$ns_ node]
$ns_ node-config -initialEnergy 100
set node_(24) [$ns_ node]
# 21 connecting to 24 at time 20.48548468411224
#
set udp_(8) [new Agent/UDP]
$ns_ attach-agent $node_(21) $udp_(8)
set null_(8) [new Agent/Null]
$ns_ attach-agent $node_(24) $null_(8)
set cbr_(8) [new Application/Traffic/CBR]
$cbr_(8) set packetSize_ 512
$cbr_(8) set interval_ 1.0
$cbr_(8) set random_ 1
$cbr_(8) set maxpkts_ 10000
$cbr_(8) attach-agent $udp_(8)
$ns_ connect $udp_(8) $null_(8)
$ns_ at 20.48548468411224 "$cbr_(8) start"
#
# 22 connecting to 9 at time 76.258212521792487
#
set udp_(9) [new Agent/UDP]
$ns_ attach-agent $node_(22) $udp_(9)
set null_(9) [new Agent/Null]
$ns_ attach-agent $node_(9) $null_(9)
set cbr_(9) [new Application/Traffic/CBR]
$cbr_(9) set packetSize_ 512
$cbr_(9) set interval_ 1.0
$cbr_(9) set random_ 1
$cbr_(9) set maxpkts_ 10000
$cbr_(9) attach-agent $udp_(9)
$ns_ connect $udp_(9) $null_(9)
$ns_ at 76.258212521792487 "$cbr_(9) start"
puts "Loading connection pattern..."
source $val(cp)
puts "Loading scenario file..."
source $val(sc)
proc finish {} {
    global ns_ tracefile namfile
    $ns_ flush-trace
    close $tracefile
    close $namfile
    exec nam manet.nam &
    exit 0
}

 for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn) } {incr i} {
    $ns_ initial_node_pos $node_($i) 20
}
 
for {set i 0} {$i < $val(nn) } {incr i} {
    $ns_ at $val(stop).000000001 "$node_($i) reset";
}
$ns_ at $val(stop) "$ns_ nam-end-wireless $val(stop)"
$ns_ at $val(stop).000000001 "puts \"NS EXITING...\"; $ns_ halt"
puts "Start Simulation..."
$ns_ run
```

The error

```
    num_nodes is set 20
INITIALIZE THE LIST xListHead
Loading connection pattern...
Loading scenario file...
Start Simulation...
SORTING LISTS ...DONE!
channel.cc:sendUp - Calc highestAntennaZ_ and distCST_
highestAntennaZ_ = 1.5,  distCST_ = 550.0
MAC_802_11: accessing MAC cache_ array out of range (src 21, dst 24, size 20)!
MAC_802_11: accessing MAC cache_ array out of range (src 24, dst 21, size 20)!
MAC_802_11: accessing MAC cache_ array out of range (src 21, dst 24, size 20)!
MAC_802_11: accessing MAC cache_ array out of range (src 21, dst 24, size 20)!
MAC_802_11: accessing MAC cache_ array out of range (src 21, dst 24, size 20)!
MAC_802_11: accessing MAC cache_ array out of range (src 21, dst 24, size 20)!
MAC_802_11: accessing MAC cache_ array out of range (src 21, dst 24, size 20)!
MAC_802_11: accessing MAC cache_ array out of range (src 21, dst 24, size 20)!
MAC_802_11: accessing MAC cache_ array out of range (src 21, dst 24, size 20)!
MAC_802_11: accessing MAC cache_ array out of range (src 21, dst 24, size 20)!
[suppressing additional MAC cache_ warnings]
NS EXITING...
```

Comment: Identical question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/653514/nodes-with-different-energies from 4 days ago. Sally, even if you open a new accound and ask the same question again, it does **not** become on-topic for this site. your previous question has gotten comments informing you of better places to ask.

Comment: The objection to the question was previously, because I put a tag to (linex), but now I put (tcl and moblie)... so why is the question not accepted???

Comment: because it's not about unix. your tagging has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Please read the WARNING output : `suppressing additional MAC cache_ warnings` ..... I.e. there are no errors. Warnings are information. ... Besides that, ns2 is ancient, and not supposed to work very well with a contemporary OS. ... There are many simulations with the same warnings.

Comment: Fwiw, might be this: https://www.nsnam.org/ (a network simulator). Probably the ns-2 variant rather than the ns-3 variant.

Comment: You should visit this anyway: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to ask about merging https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/477298/sally with https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/474588/sally